# How can I upgrade from very old version of jquery to latest one

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a task to upgrade jquery version 1.5.1 to jquery 1.11.1 and jquery ui version 1.8.11 to jquery 1.10.4. I understand that I can include both the old version and new version together by using noConflict() method. But how can I identify where I need to use the noConflict variable? What is the best way to do this migration. Please suggest.

Comment: 1) Change script `src` references to the new versions. 2) Fix errors

Comment: it's a process called debugging. you should hire a coder to do it.

Comment: @Sharky upgrading is not debugging, if the code breaks after upgrading then you go into debugging.

Comment: @RickLancee you are 100% correct. he should just hire an updater. no coding needed in this step.

Comment: OK, I've deleted my post: it's true that browser detection is a problem, and I've never used live.

Answer (score 1):

Run through the upgrade documentation for the versions of jQuery and jQueryUI. Write unit tests for your JavaScript that pass with the current versions you're using. Then upgrade your version of jQuery first, and using the documentation notes you update your code where necessary. Then fix any errors that cause your unit tests to fail. Then repeat the procedure with jQueryUI.